# Rails rake db:migrate of a recently created database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rake, dbmigrate

I have just created a database. I am trying to migrate but I am receiving a table not found error.

```
rake db:migrate 
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:211: warning:     Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/rvm/gems in PATH, mode 042777
rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Table 'law_development.users' doesn't exist: SHOW FIELDS FROM `users`
```

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

That table is created by the first migration, the database is empty (without tables).

Any help?

Comment: Did you run `rake db:create:all`?

Comment: Yes, the databases are all created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are number of reasons for this behavior. If above stated solutions didn't worked for you, then first of all try running:

```
rake db:migrate --trace
```

Examine the logs generated, definitely there would be some code that breaks migrations.

For more info you can consult [this forum](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=26700).

Answer (score 0):

Try starting with a clean database, and loading the schema directly instead of running the migrations:

```
rake db:drop db:create db:schema:load
```